# Using batch code in php

Tags: php, batch-file

Is it possible to make a php code on a webpage send out a code that the visitor will run? Like:

```
<?php
batch("echo text");
?>
```

Then it will open a cmd window that says text. If it does not work in php does it work in another launge?

Comment: PHP runs server side...

Comment: this would be a massive flaw. sounds like you are trying to do bad things.

Comment: Maybe this should be closed as ”Too broad”, if we want to interpret this as ”How to crack a computer”... ;)

Comment: Its even hard to access the client's file system before HTML5!! I can't even imagine showing a cmd window.

Answer (score 1):

PHP runs on a server and has no magical control over what happens on someone else's computer. Once the page has loaded it will be send to the requester's browser.

From there you have access to some local storage/cookies/etc., but only what the browser provides to you. If the browser would give a website access to the cmd, it would mean that any website could simply read pretty much everything on anyone's computer, or do harm in many other ways. You can imagine that this is not really secure.

The only way you can execute batch commands on someone's computer is if you or your program have access to that computer. In other words, the user must download your batch/.exe file and run it manually.